# how to test if robots.txt works in a local web server on localhost?

Tags: web-crawler, localhost, webserver, search-engine

I add a robots.txt file to the root directory of a local web server.

The url of the robots.txt file on the server is `http://localhost/myserver/robots.txt`.

The content of the robots.txt file is

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

How can I verify that the robots.txt file works for the local web server?

Do i need to install some web crawler or search engine locally and run it to verify that?

Thanks.

Comment: You are running crawlers locally? Or is this for a site that will be published on the Web at some point, and you want to test the robots.txt now (i.e., if it would work as intended as soon as the site is online)?

Comment: I want to test in development environment, not yet in production one which I don't yet have access to.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I verify that the robots.txt file works for the local web server?

As far as I know, the `robots.txt` file doesn't stop crawlers from crawling your sites. It just insists not to. That means you cannot verify if those works are not.

Instead what you can and should verify is that crawlers are able to read your `robots.txt` when they visit your site. This you can ensure by following the conventions.

That means your `robots.txt` file should be present under the root path.
If you are going to host your site under `xyz` domain, then `http://xyz/robots.txt` should be the location.

For more information, check [this](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt).

If your site is live, you can use any online tool to verify that the robots.txt is accessible. One such tool is [this](https://technicalseo.com/seo-tools/robots-txt/).

Comment: I don't understand how this is upvoted. The question is how to test if a robots.txt file is working locally, with locally being the keyword. Online checkers will not have access to a local web server so that is not a viable solution.

Comment: A robots.txt is not always the way to go, for example for Wordpress you should add a filter to create your robots.txt rules not a static file at the root.

Comment: Commenting to justify my downvote and not lose a point: This answer does not address OP's question.